# How to combine different Tkinter files in a single file with specific buttons

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter

I have created Audio Player, Video Player, Audio Clipper, Video converter, and Video enhancer in tkinter python. All the above apps have separate files. I have a root window code where I design a window having 6 buttons corresponding to the above mentioned apps. I just want to combine the code in a single (Root) window/file.
I mean, the root window with 6 buttons will be the main window. When the user click on any button, the code of that app file will run and user can perform the task.
I have all the source code but I'm unable to organize that in a single file.
How can I combine that code with the Root window?

All the code is given below:
Audio Player:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pygame
import time
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import os

root = Tk()

root.title("MP3 Player")
root.geometry("500x400")

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.mixer.init()

# Create Function To Deal With Time
def play_time():
    # Check to see if song is stopped
    if stopped:
        return

    # Grab Current Song Time
    current_time = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000
    # Convert Song Time To Time Format
    converted_current_time = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(current_time))


    # Reconstruct song with directory structure stuff
    song = playlist_box.get(ACTIVE)
    song = f'{song}.mp3'

    # Find Current Song Length
    song_mut = MP3(song)
    global song_length
    song_length = song_mut.info.length
    # Convert to time format
    converted_song_length = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(song_length))
    
    # Check to see if song is over
    if int(song_slider.get()) == int(song_length):
        stop()

    elif paused:
        # Check to see if paused, if so - pass
        pass
    
    else: 
        # Move slider along 1 second at a time
        next_time = int(song_slider.get()) + 1
        # Output new time value to slider, and to length of song
        song_slider.config(to=song_length, value=next_time)

        # Convert Slider poition to time format
        converted_current_time = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(int(song_slider.get())))

        # Output slider
        status_bar.config(text=f'Time Elapsed: {converted_current_time} of {converted_song_length}  ')


    # Add Current Time To Status Bar
    if current_time > 0:
        status_bar.config(text=f'Time Elapsed: {converted_current_time} of {converted_song_length}  ')
    
    # Create Loop To Check the time every second
    status_bar.after(1000, play_time)

# Create Function To Add One Song To Playlist
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='audio/', title="Choose A Song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3" ), ))
    # Strip out directory structure and .mp3 from song title
    song = song.replace("C:/mp3/audio/", "")
    song = song.replace(".mp3", "")
    # Add To End of Playlist
    playlist_box.insert(END, song)


#add Videos to Player
def open_file(self):
        options = {"defaultextension": ".mp3", "filetypes": [("Audio files", "*.mp3;*.wav"),("Video files", "*.mp4;*.avi;*.mkv")]}
        filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(**options)
        if filepath:
            if filepath.endswith(('.mp3', '.wav')):
                self.playlist.insert("", "end", text=os.path.basename(filepath), values=(filepath,))
                self.play_audio(filepath)
            elif filepath.endswith(('.mp4', '.avi', '.mkv')):
                self.play_video(filepath)

#Play Video in Player
def play_video(self, filepath):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.quit()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Media Player")
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Media Player")
        pygame.display.set_caption(filepath)
        movie = pygame.movie.Movie(filepath)
        movie_screen = pygame.Surface((800, 600))
        movie.set_display(movie_screen)
        movie.play()
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    movie.stop()
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
            screen.blit(movie_screen, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()




# Create Function To Add Many Songs to Playlist
def add_many_songs():
    songs = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir='audio/', title="Choose A Song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3" ), ))
    
    # Loop thru song list and replace directory structure and mp3 from song name
    for song in songs:
        # Strip out directory structure and .mp3 from song title
        song = song.replace("C:/mp3/audio/", "")
        song = song.replace(".mp3", "")
        # Add To End of Playlist
        playlist_box.insert(END, song)

# Create Function To Delete One Song From Playlist
def delete_song():
    # Delete Highlighted Song From Playlist
    playlist_box.delete(ANCHOR)

# Create Function To Delete All Songs From Playlist
def delete_all_songs():
    # Delete ALL songs 
    playlist_box.delete(0, END)

# Create Play Function
def play():
    # Set Stopped to False since a song is now playing
    global stopped
    stopped = False

    # Reconstruct song with directory structure stuff
    song = playlist_box.get(ACTIVE)
    song = f'{song}.mp3'
    
    #Load song with pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    #Play song with pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)

    # Get Song Time
    play_time()

# Create Stopped Variable
global stopped
stopped = False 
def stop():
    # Stop the song
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    # Clear Playlist Bar
    playlist_box.selection_clear(ACTIVE)

    status_bar.config(text='')

    # Set our slider to zero
    song_slider.config(value=0)

    # Set Stop Variable To True
    global stopped
    stopped = True


    
# Create Function To Play The Next Song
def next_song():
    # Reset Slider position and status bar
    status_bar.config(text='')
    song_slider.config(value=0)

    #Get current song number
    next_one = playlist_box.curselection()
    # Add One To The Current Song Number Tuple/list
    next_one = next_one[0] + 1

    # Grab the song title from the playlist
    song = playlist_box.get(next_one)
    # Add directory structure stuff to the song title
    song = f'{song}.mp3'
    #Load song with pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    #Play song with pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)

    # Clear Active Bar in Playlist
    playlist_box.selection_clear(0, END)

    # Move active bar to next song
    playlist_box.activate(next_one)

    # Set Active Bar To next song
    playlist_box.selection_set(next_one, last=None)

# Create function to play previous song
def previous_song():
    # Reset Slider position and status bar
    status_bar.config(text='')
    song_slider.config(value=0)

    #Get current song number
    next_one = playlist_box.curselection()
    # Add One To The Current Song Number Tuple/list
    next_one = next_one[0] - 1

    # Grab the song title from the playlist
    song = playlist_box.get(next_one)
    # Add directory structure stuff to the song title
    song = f'{song}.mp3'
    #Load song with pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    #Play song with pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)

    # Clear Active Bar in Playlist
    playlist_box.selection_clear(0, END)

    # Move active bar to next song
    playlist_box.activate(next_one)

    # Set Active Bar To next song
    playlist_box.selection_set(next_one, last=None)


# Create Paused Variable
global paused 
paused = False

# Create Pause Function
def pause(is_paused):
    global paused
    paused = is_paused

    if paused:
        #Unpause
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        paused = False
    else:
        #Pause
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        paused = True

#Create Volume Function
def volume(x):
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume_slider.get())

# Create a Slide Function For Song Positioning
def slide(x):
    # Reconstruct song with directory structure stuff
    song = playlist_box.get(ACTIVE)
    song = f'{song}.mp3'
    
    #Load song with pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    #Play song with pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=song_slider.get())


# Create main Frame
main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(pady=20)

# Create Playlist Box
playlist_box = Listbox(main_frame, bg="black", fg="green", width=60, selectbackground="green", selectforeground='black')
playlist_box.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Create volume slider frame
volume_frame = LabelFrame(main_frame, text="Volume")
volume_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)

# Create Volume Slider
volume_slider = ttk.Scale(volume_frame, from_=0, to=1, orient=VERTICAL, length=125, value=1, command=volume)
volume_slider.pack(pady=10)

# Create Song Slider
song_slider = ttk.Scale(main_frame, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=360, value=0, command=slide)
song_slider.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)

# Define Button Images For Controls
back_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/back50.png')
forward_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/forward50.png')
play_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/play50.png')
pause_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/pause50.png')
stop_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/stop50.png')


# Create Button Frame
control_frame = Frame(main_frame)
control_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=20)

# Create Play/Stop etc Buttons
back_button = Button(control_frame, image=back_btn_img, borderwidth=0, command=previous_song)
forward_button = Button(control_frame, image=forward_btn_img, borderwidth=0, command=next_song)
play_button = Button(control_frame, image=play_btn_img, borderwidth=0, command=play)
pause_button = Button(control_frame, image=pause_btn_img, borderwidth=0, command=lambda: pause(paused))
stop_button = Button(control_frame, image=stop_btn_img, borderwidth=0, command=stop)

back_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
forward_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
play_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
pause_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)
stop_button.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10)

# Create Main Menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

# Create Add Song Menu Dropdows
add_song_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Add Songs", menu=add_song_menu)
# Add One Song To Playlist
add_song_menu.add_command(label="Add One Song To Playlist", command=add_song)
# Add Many Songs to Playlist
add_song_menu.add_command(label="Add Many Songs To Playlist", command=add_many_songs)

# Create Delete Song Menu Dropdowns
remove_song_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Remove Songs", menu=remove_song_menu)
remove_song_menu.add_command(label="Delete A Song From Playlist", command=delete_song)
remove_song_menu.add_command(label="Delete All Songs From Playlist", command=delete_all_songs)

# Create Status Bar
status_bar = Label(root, text='', bd=1, relief=GROOVE, anchor=E)
status_bar.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM, ipady=2)


# Temporary Label
my_label = Label(root, text='')
my_label.pack(pady=20)




root.mainloop()
```

Video Player Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import cv2
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

class VideoPlayerApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Video Player")

        self.video_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        self.video_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.playing = False
        self.paused = False

        self.video_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.video_frame)
        self.video_canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.play_pause_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Play", command=self.toggle_play_pause)
        self.play_pause_button.pack()

        self.stop_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stop_button.pack()

        self.volume_scale = ttk.Scale(self.root, from_=0, to=1, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.set_volume)
        self.volume_scale.set(1)
        self.volume_scale.pack()

        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, mode='determinate')
        self.progress_bar.pack(fill=tk.X)

        self.load_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Load Video", command=self.load_video)
        self.load_button.pack()

        self.video_path = None
        self.video_capture = None
        self.video_duration = 0

        self.update_progress()

    def load_video(self):
        self.video_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Video files", "*.mp4 *.avi *.mkv")])
        if self.video_path:
            self.playing = False
            self.paused = False
            self.play_pause_button.config(text="Play")

            self.video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_path)
            self.video_duration = int(self.video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) / self.video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
            self.progress_bar.config(maximum=self.video_duration)

            self.update_progress()

    def toggle_play_pause(self):
        if self.video_path:
            if self.playing:
                self.paused = not self.paused
                if self.paused:
                    self.play_pause_button.config(text="Resume")
                else:
                    self.play_pause_button.config(text="Pause")
            else:
                self.playing = True
                self.play_pause_button.config(text="Pause")
                self.play_video()

    def play_video(self):
        if self.video_capture.isOpened() and (self.playing or self.paused):
            ret, frame = self.video_capture.read()
            if ret:
                self.show_frame(frame)
                if not self.paused:
                    self.progress_bar.step()
                    self.root.after(int(1000 / self.video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)), self.play_video)
                else:
                    self.root.after(100, self.play_video)
            else:
                self.stop()
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Video playback finished.")

    def stop(self):
        self.playing = False
        self.paused = False
        self.play_pause_button.config(text="Play")
        if self.video_capture:
            self.video_capture.release()
        self.progress_bar.stop()
        self.progress_bar.config(value=0)

    def set_volume(self, volume):
        pass  # Implement volume control

    def update_progress(self):
        pass  # No need to update progress here since play_video function takes care of it

    def show_frame(self, frame):
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = tk.PhotoImage(data=cv2.imencode('.png', frame)[1].tobytes())
        self.video_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=img)
        self.video_canvas.image = img

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = VideoPlayerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Audio Clipper Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pydub import AudioSegment

# Function to create a new audio file with the selected range
def create_new_file():
    # Get the values entered by the user
    file_path = file_path_entry.get()
    start_min = int(start_min_entry.get())
    start_sec = int(start_sec_entry.get())
    end_min = int(end_min_entry.get())
    end_sec = int(end_sec_entry.get())

    # Open the selected file
    song = AudioSegment.from_file(file_path, format="mp3")

    # Calculate the start and end times in milliseconds
    start = ((start_min * 60) + start_sec) * 1000
    end = ((end_min * 60) + end_sec) * 1000

    # Extract the selected range from the song
    clip = song[start:end]

    # Ask the user to select a save location and filename
    save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".mp3")

    # Save the extracted clip as a new mp3 file
    clip.export(save_path, format="mp3")

    # Show a message to indicate that the new file has been created
    status_label.config(text="New Audio file is created and saved")

# Create the main window
root = Tk()
root.title("Audio Clipper")

# Create a frame to hold the file path input field and browse button
file_frame = Frame(root)
file_frame.pack(pady=10)

file_path_label = Label(file_frame, text="File Path:")
file_path_label.pack(side=LEFT)

file_path_entry = Entry(file_frame, width=50)
file_path_entry.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)

browse_button = Button(file_frame, text="Browse", command=lambda: file_path_entry.insert(0, filedialog.askopenfilename()))
browse_button.pack(side=LEFT)

# Create a frame to hold the start/end time input fields
time_frame = Frame(root)
time_frame.pack()

start_label = Label(time_frame, text="Start Time (mm:ss):")
start_label.pack(side=LEFT)

start_min_entry = Entry(time_frame, width=2)
start_min_entry.insert(END, "1")
start_min_entry.pack(side=LEFT)

start_colon_label = Label(time_frame, text=":")
start_colon_label.pack(side=LEFT)

start_sec_entry = Entry(time_frame, width=2)
start_sec_entry.insert(END, "10")
start_sec_entry.pack(side=LEFT)

end_label = Label(time_frame, text="End Time (mm:ss):")
end_label.pack(side=LEFT)

end_min_entry = Entry(time_frame, width=2)
end_min_entry.insert(END, "2")
end_min_entry.pack(side=LEFT)

end_colon_label = Label(time_frame, text=":")
end_colon_label.pack(side=LEFT)

end_sec_entry = Entry(time_frame, width=2)
end_sec_entry.insert(END, "5")
end_sec_entry.pack(side=LEFT)

# Create a button to initiate the audio extraction
extract_button = Button(root, text="Create Audio Clip", command=create_new_file)
extract_button.pack(pady=10)

# Create a label to show the status of the extraction process
status_label = Label(root, text="", fg="green")
status_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Video Converter Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def open_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print("Selected file:", file_path)
    #file_label.config(text="Selected file: " + file_path)
    convert_to_mp3(file_path)

def convert_to_mp3(file_path):
    if file_path:
        video = VideoFileClip(file_path)
        mp3_file_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + ".mp3"
        video.audio.write_audiofile(mp3_file_path)
        print("File converted to MP3:", mp3_file_path)
        status_label.config(text="File is Converted")
        save_button = tk.Button(root, text="Save File", command=lambda: save_file(mp3_file_path))
        save_button.pack(pady=10)

def save_file(mp3_file_path):
    save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".mp3", filetypes=[("MP3 Files", "*.mp3")])
    if save_path:
        os.rename(mp3_file_path, save_path)
        status_label.config(text="File is Saved")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Video File Selector")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Select Video File", command=open_file)
button.pack(pady=20)

file_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
file_label.pack()

status_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
status_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Video Enhancer Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def process_video():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a Video", filetypes=[("Video files", "*.mp4;*.avi")])

    if file_path:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)

        # Get video properties
        width = int(cap.get(3))
        height = int(cap.get(4))
        fps = int(cap.get(5))

        # Create VideoWriter object to save the processed video
        save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".avi", filetypes=[("Video files", "*.avi")])
        if not save_path:
            return

        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(save_path, fourcc, fps, (width, height))

        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break

            # Sharpening using addWeighted()
            sharpened = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 7.5, cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (7, 7), 2), -6.5, 0)

            # Apply bilateral blur
            bilateral_blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(sharpened, 9, 75, 75)

            # Display the original, sharpened, and blurred video frames
            cv2.imshow("Original Video", frame)
            cv2.imshow("Sharpened Video", sharpened)
            cv2.imshow("Blurred Video", bilateral_blur)

            # Write the processed frame to the output video
            out.write(bilateral_blur)

            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        # Enable Save button
        save_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

        # Store the processed video path in the global variable for saving
        global processed_video_path
        processed_video_path = save_path

def save_video():
    save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".avi", filetypes=[("Video files", "*.avi")])
    if save_path and processed_video_path:
        # Copy the processed video file to the user-specified location
        import shutil
        shutil.copyfile(processed_video_path, save_path)
        print(f"Processed video saved to {save_path}")

# Create the main application window
app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Video Processing App")

# Create and pack a button to trigger video processing
process_button = tk.Button(app, text="Process Video", command=process_video)
process_button.pack(pady=20)

# Create and pack a button to save the processed video (initially disabled)
save_button = tk.Button(app, text="Save Video", command=save_video, state=tk.DISABLED)
save_button.pack(pady=20)

# Run the Tkinter main loop
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to write another module called `main.py`. From there, you can use a file menu instead of creating six buttons. Noticed, you don't do instances of `tk.Tk()` for each module. Just replace `tk.Toplevel()`. Noticed. you don't need to add a `mainloop()` for each module. Only `main.py` will handle all of this. On file menu, you need to  add this  Audio Player, Video Player, Audio Clipper, Video converter, and Video enhancer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` to execute the script in another process.